# Better ads plugin has 500.000 entries in wp_postmeta

Tags: plugins, database, mysql, phpmyadmin

My wp_postmeta table is huge, around 1.2 million entries, about half of those are caused by *bs* entries (_bs_via_rel_2, _bs_review_verdict, _bs_source_url_2, _bs_source_url_3... etc). From what little I could see 99% of these entries are empty. Also while I do have the better adds plugin I'm currently running only one Ad on my frontpage and nothing else.

How could I clean up my wp_postmeta table from these empty entries, is this expected behavior for better ads? Also for reference I have 20.000 posts on the page.

Comment: The plugin is likely just poorly written. I suggest bringing the issue up with the plugin author. 3rd-party plugins are off-topic here, after all.

Answer (score -1):

Try it like this:
1. Create backup.
2. Export the table to a sql file, open it in a text editor, select and delete unnecessary records (ex. by regexp), then import it back.